# List of calculi suitable for generic computation

Tags: universal-computation, calculus-of-constructions

I'm looking for a list of calculi suitable for generic computation such as Lambda calculus, Pi calculus, and event calculus. What else do we have? Thank you.

Comment: What is "generic" here?

Comment: Indeed! And what counts as a calculus?

Comment: Dears, I am merely exploring the area here so excuse my impreciseness. By generic, I mean suitable for representing and reasoning about most of common programming languages, regardless of details as I will take this list and educate myself further. If I knew what counts as calculus, I would have included it in my question, and that is why I mentioned a few examples of my fuzzy notion of calculus. Now could you please help me?

Comment: In the last 100 or so years, we have learned that essentially all formalism / calculi / programming languages are equivalent, in that they can represent the same computation. This is also called the [Church-Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis). So unless you put additional constraints on what you want from such a calculus, just about anything, in particular any programming language fits the bill. Your question might be more suitable for [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).